# AWK case sensitive

Tags: shell, awk

My CSV file is like this >>

```
ABC XYZ 111 FRANCE
GGG KKK 222 France
HHH     666 France
France     886 USA
```

when I run the command

```
$ awk -F',' '($4 ~ /FRANCE/) { print $4 }' test.csv
```

it shows me 
FRANCE 
only

All I want it to read France , FRANCE , FrAnce and france must be in 4th column,

how can I ignore case sensitivity and read 4th for france?

Comment: Where is the `','` in the file you are trying to use a the *Field Separator* (e.g. your `-F','`)??

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'tolower($NF)=="france"{print $NF}' Input_file
```

OR in case you have comma delimited Input_file try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} tolower($NF)=="france"{print $NF}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Or with GNU `awk` use `IGNORCASE`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $NF=="france"{print $NF}'  Input_file
```

OR in case you have comma delimited Input_file.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";IGNORECASE=1} $NF=="france"{print $NF}'  Input_file
```

Comment: All 4 solutions you gave provide no results.. 

 awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";IGNORECASE=1} $4=="france"{print $4}' test.csv 
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $4=="france"{print $4}'  test.csv 
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} tolower($4)=="FRANCE"{print $4}' test.csv 
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} tolower($4)=="FRA"{print $4}' test.csv 
and so on.. 

I actually try a lot with these earlier but got nothing from the internet... 

The summary is   France must be in 4th column ... awk must not read the 1st column.

If I write France / FRANCE / france, it must read all frane similar to "grep -i " but in 4th column only...

Comment: @CorOmnes, Yes it is not reading 1st column.

Comment: PS: I am using mac terminal

Comment: @CorOmnes, Is it not giving your correct results? It worked fine for me.

Comment: I saw 3rd option, it should work for me... pls have a look... >>  

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t1CYhbN0ZmCfPgdKIPzj-JDhnlduBV9U/view

Comment: @CorOmnes, sorry I can't open this link in office system, please type it and let me know then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202396/discussion-between-cor-omnes-and-ravindersingh13).